# How do i resolve this error?Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote a code to multiply 2 multidimensional arrays.

input-2

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
3 2
2 3
1 2
2 1
2 2
12 4
7 6
2 3
2 4 6
3 5 7
```

This is the code I wrote, but it is showing
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException.`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// Other imports go here, Do NOT change the class name
class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int n = sc.nextInt(); 
    int x,y,l,m;
    while(n!=0) 
    {  
      x=sc.nextInt(); 
      y=sc.nextInt();
    int a[][] = new int[x][y]; 
      for(int i=0;i<x;i++) 
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++) 
          a[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
       l=sc.nextInt(); 
      m=sc.nextInt();
    int b[][] = new int[l][m]; 
      for(int i=0;i<l;i++) 
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) 
          b[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
      int c[][] = new int[x][m]; 
      for(int i=0;i<x;i++) 
      { 
      for(int j=0;j<m;j++) 
      { 
      c[i][j]=0; 
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++) 
        { 
        c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];
        } 
        System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
      } 
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `n` never seems to change, so there should not be a while loop checking for `n != 0`. You also seem to be missing quite a lot of braces on your `for`-loops. Also also, when the `Scanner` is no longer needed, you should close it to avoid resource leaks, `sc.close()`.

Comment: I'd *strongly* advise you to reformat your code in an IDE, and edit it - at the moment it's very hard to follow because the indentation doesn't follow the actual code structure. I'd also suggest using braces on all loops and if statements, even if the bodies are single statements - it makes it a lot easier to spot mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Your program is expecting more input than what you have supplied it.

Note the line,

```
while(n!=0)
```

From the sample input, I am presuming that you want to do the addition only once. In that case, you should use

```
if(n!=0)
```

However, if you want to repeat the operation multiple times for different input arrays, change the value of `n` after each iteration to prevent infinite loop. Also, make sure you supply the required size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your input and 1 problem with your code.

Problems with your input:

1. What I understand from the code and the input you have posted in the question is that you want the loop to run two times. But you have forgotten to enter the value for n in your input. So you need to add 2 as the first line.
2. Scanner requires a delimiter after the last line of the input so you have to insert a new line after the last line in your input so that the last actual line of your input which is '3 5 7' is taken up by the scanner code.

So your input will be something like this:

> 2
> 2 3
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 3 2
> 2 3
> 1 2
> 2 1
> 2 2
> 12 4
> 7 6
> 2 3
> 2 4 6
> 3 5 7

Now the problem with your code. You need to add n-- at the end of the while loop otherwise it will get into an infinite loop.